# Postgresql : Trigger in background

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I need to have my trigger to run after the field s updated or to run in background. Since for now as soon as the trigger is fired the UI is blocked until the procedure in the trigger itself is executed.
Anyway to make the trigger in such a way that as soon as the field is updated, the UI do not block away.

I have tried:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER property_created_simple_prod_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON properties DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE simple_production_materialized_view_procedure_trigger();
```

But hard luck nothing works.

Comment: Run whatever the method that call the update into a separated thread.

Comment: please update the question with list of commands and results, commenting what you get and what you want to get instead

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL doesn't have background procedures/triggers, so you can't do that directly.

What I suggest us having the trigger send a `NOTIFY` that your application `LISTEN`s to. Have the application's `LISTEN`ing thread be a separate connection, managed by a separate thread, that does background processing when it receives notifications.

Comment: What about background workers? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bgworker.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sure, that's an option if they want to implement their own extension. But there's nothing canned to do it. Though there are proposals (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BTgmoam66dTzCP8N2cRcS6S6dBMFX%2BJMba%2BmDf68H%3DKAkNjPQ@mail.gmail.com) and extensions (https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background)

Comment: and https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+TgmoaXQEt4tZ03FtQhnzeDEMzBck+Lrni0UWHVVgOTnA6C1w@mail.gmail.com

Comment: `pg_background` may be an option, but really, I'd be going for a listen/notify based approach, that's what it's for. I've written bgworkers, and it's _not_ going to be fun for someone who doesn't know postgres's code well to write an async trigger helper. They'll need to know the IPC mechanisms and all sorts.